# PHP if condition microoptimalisation

Tags: php, if-statement, resources, interpreter, execution

## What is better and why?

> if ($variable === null)

or

> if (null === $variable)

1. How PHP interpreter (PHP 7 vs PHP 8) parse conditions like this?
2. Is there any differance with resource consumption and script execution time?
3. How big is it? How much faster?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: There's no difference in performance. They are the same operation.